# Connecting database to android using json

Tags: php, android, json

As I am new to application development I am using JSON to connect to my database using PHP but I am having an error with the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText etemail, etpass;
    Button login, register;
    TextView tError;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    //TextView PToDoc;

    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    //private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static final String KEY_REFERRED_AS = "referred_as";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_CARD = "card";
    private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACT_NO = "contact_no";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_DATEOFBIRTH = "dateofbirth";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setting default screen to sign_in.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
        etpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        tError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);


        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                String email = etemail.getText().toString();
                String password = etpass.getText().toString();
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                Log.d("Button", "Login");
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                try {
                   if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) == null) {
                        tError.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_REFERRED_AS),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_CARD),
                                    json_user.getString(KEY_DATEOFBIRTH),json_user.getString(KEY_ADDRESS),                                    json_user.getString(KEY_CONTACT_NO),json_user.getString(KEY_ID));
                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);

                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);

                            // Close Login Screen
                            finish();
                       }else{
                            // Error in login
                            tError.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                       }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Register.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });


    }   
}
```

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: Json object could connect to my database but when it come for me to link it to my home.class he never happen .. am thinking maybe is not saving on my sqlite database but i have try to find the error but i am finding it difficult

Answer (score 0):

On the click event of login button get the email and password and add it to JSONObject and then pass it to a asyn class to send it to a particular weblink
related code is as follows:

```
class SendAsyn extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {
String url = "http://Yourweblink.com/Yourdbfile.php";
Boolean repeat=true;

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    JSONObject json = params[0];
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);
    String resFromServer="null";
    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("regis=" + json.toString());
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        post.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response;
        Log.i("URL",post.getParams().toString());
        response = client.execute(post);
        resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
                .toString(response.getEntity());

        if(resFromServer.trim().equals("successfull")){
            LoginActivity.suc=true;
            LoginActivity.error=false;
            Log.i("here we are","successfull"+resFromServer);
        }else{
            String[] tokens=resFromServer.split("~");
            Log.i("here we are else",resFromServer);
            if(tokens[0].equals("Error")){
                Log.i("here we are error",tokens[1]);
                LoginActivity.error=true;
                LoginActivity.suc=false;
            }
        }

    //Log.i("Response", resFromServer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return jsonResponse;
}
```

}

And call this class by using

```
 SendAsyn transmitter = new SendAsyn();
 transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[]{Your JSONObject});
```